AWS managed apache flink increasing checkpoint size
I am using AWS managed apache flink, using scala 2.12 and flink 1.15 (flink-scala) .
i added a keyed process function and a ValueState.
ever since, the checkpoint size is slowly increasing, eventually resulting in a restart.
here is the code for declaring the ttl and the state
        val ttlConfig = StateTtlConfig.newBuilder(Time.minutes(5))
                .setUpdateType(StateTtlConfig.UpdateType.OnCreateAndWrite)
                .setStateVisibility(StateTtlConfig.StateVisibility.NeverReturnExpired)
            .cleanupFullSnapshot()
                .build
        val descriptor = new ValueStateDescriptor[MyClass](s"MyClass",classOf[MyClass])
        descriptor.enableTimeToLive(ttlConfig)
        myState = getRuntimeContext.getState(descriptor)

the amount of keys coming in is bounded, around 7000, so its not a data issue.
after triggering a savepoiont the size decreases drastically, and then goes back again at the next checkpoint invocation.
tried to call rocksDB compaction .cleanupInRocksdbCompactFilter(10) but it didnt help either.


Are you sure you're using RocksDB for state?
Are you sure your keyed process function isn't regularly updating state for most/all keys, and thus TTL won't happen?


yes, AWS managed solution uses rocksDB for state
i have a bounded amount of keys. if they are all updating the state size should stay the same
